# Access IIf Query with multiple OR conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

This may be a silly question, but I'm trying to fill a column in an Access query using an Iif statement and it's not working as I'd like.  This is what I have:

```
Action: IIf([NewComments]="A" Or "E" Or "F" Or "D","CANCEL","SUSPEND")
```

When I run that it generates CANCEL for every cell, even though that's not correct.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN`:

```
IIf([NewComments] IN ("A", "E", "F", "D"), "CANCEL", "SUSPEND")
```

Comment: This works but when I run it it generates an Enter Parameter box for NewComments.  How can I get rid of that?

Comment: @Katie . . . Presumably that is your intention, given that this is the column in your question.  Perhaps you need to pay closer attention to what columns are in the table.

Comment: NewComments is a column that is already filled in in the table.  I'm looking for an Iif statement that will look at the values in that column and give the outputs listed above accordingly.  Is there a better way to do that?